Modelling from curve
I'm terrible at creating models from scratch - I tend to make objects by drawing the shape in illustrator and adding a whole cocktail of modifiers to turn it into a 3D model in blender. I have made this shape with Bezier curves but I can't for the life of me turn it into a clean mesh. Anyone have any tips?
I have attached two images, one is of a real mini model that i am trying to make a cleaner version of in blender and the second is my curves. Thanks in advance :)

what do you mean "I can't for the life of me turn it into a clean mesh", what does it give if you right click > Convert to Mesh? Please share your file so that we can try

Looks good so far. Don't take this the wrong way… do you think your issue is a technical problem, or a knowledge gap? How far did you get after the pictured step? What problem did you encounter, and what does it look like when it goes wrong? We can't provide free-form tutorials and advice.

Sure, i apologise for lack of info - by clean i mean like clean topology. When i convert it to a mesh its very messy. I need to be able to sculpt into it or at least make the whole top spherical and have the bottom flat. How do I attach the file? - Thanks

Here is an image of the main problem with mesh https://ibb.co/PFkryQQ

You could create a cube, select the face ring, extrude individual faces:

Extrude until you get this shape, select all:

Bevel with CtrlB:


Thank you, this is deffo easier
